# Is there a way to concatenate multiple vectors simply?

Tags: c++, stl

There currently exist ways to concatenate or merge two vectors with one function.

But, it seems that there's no way to concatenate or merge more than three vectors with one function.

For example,

```
vector<string> a = {"a", "b"};
vector<string> b = {"c", "d"};
vector<string> c = {"e", "f"};
vector<string> d = {"g", "h"};

// newVector has to include {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}
vector<string> newVector = function(a, b, c, d);
```

If there is not, it seems that this can be implemented by using **variadic template**.

But, I can't imagine how it can be implemented by **variadic template**.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure about variadic templates, what about just `for (auto v : { a, b, c, d }) { newVector.insert(newVector.end(), v.begin(), v.end()); }`? It's only 3 lines of code and it's pretty clear what is happening

Comment: @Tas Thank you, that is the interesting solution. But could I functionalize it, assuming vector type can be anything such as int, double (merging same types of vector)

Comment: @sungjuncho one thing to watch out for about `{a, b, c, d}` is that it makes a copy of `a`, `b`, etc. You could use `{&a, &b, &c, &d}` to get around that. See my answer for a functionized example of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use [range v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), you can simply do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> allVec = ranges::view::concat(a, b, c, d);
```

See [demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76a1b3ba42712b12).

You can use this with any vector type.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution with `variadic templates`

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void appendVector(vector<T>& v1, vector<T>& v2, Args... args)
{
     v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
     appendVector(v1, args...);
}

template<typename T>
void appendVector(vector<T>& v1, vector<T>& v2)
{
    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
}
```

You just need to append your vectors:

```
vector<string> newVector;
newVector.reserve(a.size()+b.size()+c.size()+d.size());
appendVector(newVector, a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: As an optimization, is there a way to make this approach be able to preallocate the final size of the target vector with `reserve()` before inserting the input vectors? It would be nice if the target vector didn't have to potentially re-grow its capacity on each insert.

Comment: Also, unless I'm reading this code incorrectly, doesn't this code modify the input vectors when more than 1 input vector is being appended? That would probably not be a desirable side effect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for checking out side effect. It is fixed now. Regarding `reserve()` not really sure how efficient it is.

Comment: You might even remove recursive call and compute reservation size inside the function [Demo in C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c81d5b84c757ce38)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> merge(std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>*> vecs)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    for(auto v : vecs) { size += v->size(); }
    std::vector<T> ret;
    ret.reserve(size);
    for(auto v : vecs) { ret.insert(ret.end(), v->begin(), v->end()); }
    return ret;
}
```

```
std::vector<std::string> a = {"a", "b"};
std::vector<std::string> b = {"c", "d"};
std::vector<std::string> c = {"e", "f"};
std::vector<std::string> d = {"g", "h"};

std::vector<std::string> newVector = merge({&a, &b, &c, &d});
```

[Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/DqO9lj)

Alternatively:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> merge(std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<const std::vector<T>>> vecs)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    for(auto &v : vecs) { size += v.get().size(); }
    std::vector<T> ret;
    ret.reserve(size);
    for(auto &v : vecs) { ret.insert(ret.end(), v.get().begin(), v.get().end()); }
    return ret;
}
```

```
std::vector<std::string> a = {"a", "b"};
std::vector<std::string> b = {"c", "d"};
std::vector<std::string> c = {"e", "f"};
std::vector<std::string> d = {"g", "h"};

std::vector<std::string> newVector = merge({std::cref(a), std::cref(b), std::cref(c), std::cref(d)});
```

[Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/D6qTWV)

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution. Variation on the solution proposed by @miradham.
reserve is automized, and it concatenates any standard container into an std::vector.

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::vector<T> concat(Args... args)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    v.reserve((args.size() + ...));
    (v.insert(v.end(), args.begin(), args.end()),...);
    return v;
}
```